# Ignoring of figsize with geopandas

Tags: matplotlib, geopandas

I try to plot 2 points on map:

```
import geopandas as gp
from shapely.geometry import Point

points = {'name': ['point1','point2'],
          'geometry': [Point(37.710624, 55.859523), Point(37.705523,55.675104)]
         }
gdf = gp.GeoDataFrame(points, columns = ['name', 'geometry'],crs="epsg:4326")
gdf.plot(color="red", figsize=(5,5))
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXEJB.png)

Why result is not 5X5 and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The resulting figure is 5 tall. GeoPandas plot is normally limited to geometry, you cannot specify the aspect of the figure yourself (you will in 0.8) to avoid distortion of geometry. If you want to show some empty area around your two points, you need to set specific `xlim` limits to axis. If your points were horizontally distributed, you would need `ylim`. Alternatively you can set both.

```
ax = gdf.plot(color="red", figsize=(5,5))
ax.set_xlim(37.6, 37.8)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! IMHO it would be more logical to calculate `xlim` and  `ylim` automatically to match figsize.